# Warnings trying to read Spark 1.6.X Parquet into Spark 2.X

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

When attempting to load a spark 1.6.X parquet file into spark 2.X I am seeing many `WARN` level statements.

```
  16/08/11 12:18:51 WARN CorruptStatistics: Ignoring statistics because created_by could not be parsed (see PARQUET-251): parquet-mr version 1.6.0
  org.apache.parquet.VersionParser$VersionParseException: Could not parse created_by: parquet-mr version 1.6.0 using format: (.+) version ((.*) )?\(build ?(.*)\)
    at org.apache.parquet.VersionParser.parse(VersionParser.java:112)
    at org.apache.parquet.CorruptStatistics.shouldIgnoreStatistics(CorruptStatistics.java:60)
    at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetStatistics(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:263)
    at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:567)
    at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.readParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:544)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:431)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.initialize(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.initialize(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:343)
    at [rest of stacktrace omitted]
```

I am running 2.1.0 release and there are multitudes of these warnings. Is there any way - short of changing logging level to ERROR - to suppress these?

It seems these were the result of a fix made - but the warnings may not yet be removed.   Here are some details from that JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17993

> I have built the code from the PR and it indeed succeeds reading the
>   data.   I have tried doing df.count() and now I'm swarmed with
>   warnings like this (they are just keep getting printed endlessly in
>   the terminal):

Setting the logging level to `ERROR` is a last ditch approach: it is swallowing messages we rely upon for standard monitoring.  Has anyone found a workaround to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the time being - i.e until/unless this spark/parquet bug were fixed - I will be adding the following to the `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
```

The location is:

- when running against external spark server: `$SPARK_HOME/conf/log4j.properties`
- when running locally inside `Intellij` (or other IDE): `src/main/resources/log4j.properties`

Comment: Can you provide more details as to where you will update the following line? log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR i.e. in Hive log4j.properties ?

Comment: @Jay . Sorry I did not notice your comment until now. Updated my answer for that info.